# Vector of thread pointers, push_back causes crash

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to C++, and I was lately looking into concurrency.
I tried to run this simple program demonstrating threads:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>

void threadWork()
{
    printf("WORKER THREAD EXECUTING");
}

int main()
{
    printf("INSTANTIATE THREAD\n");
    std::vector<std::thread *> threadList;
    threadList.push_back(&std::thread(&threadWork));
    printf("THREAD INSTANTIATED JOINING...\n");
    for (std::thread* t : threadList)
    {
        t->join();
    }
    printf("THREADS JOINED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After the call to push_back() the program crashes with a call to abort() (I am running this on Windows)
Why is this code crashing at runtime?

Comment: Why do you keep a vector of _pointers_? And what does your pointer point to? Do you understand pointers?

Comment: You cannot take address of a temporary.

Comment: N.B. this won't even compile outside of VS

Comment: The pointer added to the vector points to the address of the instantiated thread object (&std::thread(&threadWork)) as far as i understand. And i am using pointers because i am practicing and as i understood it pointers are more flexible.

Comment: *and as i understood it pointers are more flexible* -- No, that is not a reason to use pointers.  You use pointers when you need to use pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::thread *> threadList;
threadList.push_back(&std::thread(&threadWork));
```

Here you take the address of a temporary.

This is not permitted in C++, but Visual Studio lets you do it anyway.

That's a shame because the temporary is destroyed at the end of the call, so your vector contains nothing but a dangling pointer.

Furthermore, since you are not `join()`ing or `detach()`ing the thread, destroying its `std::thread` (which happens when it goes out of scope) causes your program to `std::terminate()` (commonly considered a crash).

I recommend re-reading the chapter in your C++ book about thread management, so that you can be assured of effecting it in a safe manner.

---

Forget about pointers here; you don't need them. Instead, just have a nice simple vector of threads, and directly construct your elements using `emplace_back`, like this:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
threadList.emplace_back(&threadWork);
```

Then ensure you `join()` your threads before program completion.

Comment: I think his underlying problem is that he is not very versed in the differnt types of memory in C++ (heap, stack, static, thread local, ...). If he was, he would not even try what he tried.

Comment: @BitTickler Ironically, C++ knows nothing about "heap" or "stack". You are referring to storage durations. Time to brush up ;)

Answer (score 1):

The program aborts because std thread aborts if you destroy it when it is running or finished.

This happens because you are storing a vector of pointers and taking the address of temporary objects.  The first is a bad idea, the second is illegal in C++ but MSVC permits it by default.

In C++ you should default to using values, especially with std library types.  And when you don't use values, use smart pointers.  Using raw pointer should usually be either only for some function args, sometimes in a struct/class with reference semantics, or when doing C interop.

So here,

```
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
```

is a vector of threads.  No pointless pointers.

```
threadList.emplace_back(&threadWork);
```

that creates a new thread running threadwork/

```
for(auto& thread:threadList){
   thread.join();
}
```

that joins the threads; this will wait until the thread is done.  Failure to do something like this will make your program abort.

All together:

```
printf("INSTANTIATE THREAD\n");
std::vector<std::thread> threadList;
threadList.emplace_back(&threadWork);
printf("THREAD INSTANTIATED\n");
for(auto& thread:threadList){
   thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Hah, TIL `~thread()` doesn't `detach()`. Thought it did, because Boost's used to, but even that impl has moved on since I last bothered looking into it. Shows how important it is to keep up-to-date with even the most basic functions I suppose...